# Group/order text rows in oracle how?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this query in oralce 11g:

```
SELECT (case when APIPueFun='A' then Auditor.UNombre else null end) audi,
       (case when APIPueFun='S' then Supervisor.UNombre else null end) supe
FROM SATAPersInte, 
     SATUsuario Auditor,
     SATUsuario Supervisor
WHERE APINCIUsu = Auditor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APINCIUsu = Supervisor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APIPueFun in ('A','S') 
  AND APINCIAud =134440;
```

I have this result:

```
NOMBREAU                                     NOMBRESU                            
-------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------
 Lic. Marcela Espinosa Muciño                 (null)                              
 P.L.A.E. Alejandro Antonio                   (null)                              
 (null)                                       L.C. Claudia Serrano Cobos          
 (null)                                       Lic. Rosalba Montero Gómez          
 (null)                                       Lic. Víctor Antonio Lemus
 (null)                                       Lic. Yatzaret Velarde
```

But I want this result:

```
NOMBREAU                                     NOMBRESU                            
-------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------
 Lic. Marcela Espinosa Muciño                 L.C. Claudia Serrano Cobos                             
 P.L.A.E. Alejandro Antonio                   Lic. Rosalba Montero Gómez                              
 (null)                                       Lic. Víctor Antonio Lemus          
 (null)                                       Lic. Yatzaret Velarde          
 (null)                                       (null)   
 (null)                                       (null)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the logic behind? Knowing the data in the tables and the reason why you expect that output would be useful to clarify your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want two unrelated columns of data next to each other. This is unusual. To do that you'll need to assign each audi and supe a number and then join them together on that number. You can use ROW_NUMBER to do that

```
With data as (
SELECT (case when APIPueFun='A' then Auditor.UNombre else null end) audi,
       (case when APIPueFun='S' then Supervisor.UNombre else null end) supe
FROM SATAPersInte, 
     SATUsuario Auditor,
     SATUsuario Supervisor
WHERE APINCIUsu = Auditor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APINCIUsu = Supervisor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APIPueFun in ('A','S') 
  AND APINCIAud =134440) ,
rowNumbers as 
( Select 
      audi,
      row_number() over (order by audi) aRN,
      supe,
      row_number() over (order by supe) sRN
 FROM
      data)
Select
      a.audi,
      s.supe
FROM
    rowNumbers a
    FULL OUTER JOIN rowNumbers s
    on a.aRN = s.sRN
ORDER BY
    a.aRN,
    s.sRN
```

Comment: Yes, It's what I was looking for, Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (case when APIPueFun='A' then Auditor.UNombre else null end) audi,
       (case when APIPueFun='S' then Supervisor.UNombre else null end) supe
FROM SATAPersInte, 
     SATUsuario Auditor,
     SATUsuario Supervisor
WHERE APINCIUsu = Auditor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APINCIUsu = Supervisor.UNCIUsua 
  AND APIPueFun in ('A','S') 
  AND APINCIAud =134440
ORDER BY NOMBREAU DESC NULLS LAST
       , NOMBRESU DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: perhaps I missed something. Why would adding an order by change nulls to non-null values?

Comment: They didn't, adding 'nulls first' or 'nulls last' to the order by clause tells Oracle whether to put the nulls before or after values.

Comment: Then I think you misunderstood the question. If you look at the data in the actual and dersired result you'll see the values in the first two rows in the second column go from null to non-null while the values in the first column remain unchanged.

Comment: If you want a specific order, you must specify that in an **ORDER BY** clause. SQL does not guarantee any specific order without the **ORDER BY**.